# Min and max not working correctly when using single low digit numbers

Tags: java, arrays, max, min

I'm setting up my array from a user input and then trying to find the min and max.But it only seems to work perfect for finding the max and not the min.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class GradeBookKeeper 
{
  public static void main(String arg[])
{
  int numItems;
  int[] items;
  double sum=0;
  Scanner scan= new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("Enter the number of students: ");
  numItems=scan.nextInt();
  items=new int [numItems];
  int largest=items[0],smallest=items[0];
  for (int i = 0 ; i < items.length; i++ )
  {
      System.out.println("Enter the grade for student "+(i+1)+":");
      items[i] = scan.nextInt();
      sum = sum + items[i];
      if(largest < items[i])
      {
          largest = items[i];
      } 
      else 
      {
          smallest = items[i];
      } 
  }
  System.out.printf("The average is "+"%.2f\n",sum/items.length);
  System.out.println("The minimum is: "+smallest);
  System.out.println("The maximum is: "+largest);
  scan.close();
}
}
```

//output

Enter the number of students: 
4

Enter the grade for student 1:

2

Enter the grade for student 2:

1

Enter the grade for student 3:

2

Enter the grade for student 4:

3

The average is 2.00

The minimum is: 2

The maximum is: 3

Comment: why do you even need an array?

Comment: well its part of the hw the user gives the array a length then the user inputs as many elements as the length

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you're only setting `smallest` when you have not found a new largest element while traversing the items array. So instead of an `else`, change it to another if statement to see if the item you are iterating on is less than your current smallest item like so,

```
if(largest < items[i])
{
    largest = items[i];
} 
if(smallest > items[i])
{
    smallest = items[i];
}
```

Also, you're initializing `smallest` and `largest` to the first element in `items` which will default to 0 since the items array is empty at that point. Try initializing `largest` to the smallest possible grade and `smallest` to the largest possible grade like so (currently using the min and max integer values),

```
int largest=Integer.MIN_VALUE,smallest=INTEGER.MAX_VALUE;
```

The reason for this is that you're never going to find a grade smaller than 0, and since that's what you had before, the smallest grade would have always been 0.

Comment: @redsky No problem, if you found it helpful then please consider upvoting or accepting the answer. Good luck coding!

Answer (score 0):

I am only here for an ***alternative*** version. And the way it works is sorting the array(lowest to highest), and then just getting lowest as the smallest, and highest as the largest number.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GradeBookKeeper
{
 public static void main(String[] arg)
  {
    Scanner scan= new Scanner(System.in);

    int[] items;
    double sum=0;
    int numItems,largest,smallest;

    System.out.print("Enter the number of students:  ");
    numItems=scan.nextInt();
    items=new int [numItems];
    largest=smallest=items[0];

    for(int i=0;i<items.length;i++)
    {
        System.out.print("Enter the grade for student "+(i+1)+": ");
        items[i] = scan.nextInt();
        sum+=items[i];

    }
    for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        Arrays.sort(items);
        largest=items[items.length-1];
        smallest=items[0];
    }


    System.out.printf("The average is "+"%.2f\n",sum/items.length);
    System.out.println("The minimum is: "+smallest);
    System.out.println("The maximum is: "+largest);
    scan.close();
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
if (largest < items[i])
largest = items[i]
else if (smallest > items[i])
smallest = items[i]
```

Also smallest's first value should be one of the items as none of the grades can be smaller than 0

This should work,
I hope that you understand